# How to Load another page onclick of appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with some rows. in this table i have Add button to append rows when clicked. my question is how can i load ajax seconpage in class = loadi in  rows when Add clicked?
i wrote some codes but the codes is not working to load second page in div with class loadi. here is my Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>');
  });
  $(".loadi").load("secondpage.html");
})
```

```css
.add {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span class="add">Add +</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `load()` within the click handler on the content that you just appended. Your current logic doesn't work as you call `load()` before the element exists, therefore nothing happens. Try this:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    var $tr = $('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>').insertAfter('#mytable tr:last');
    $tr.find(".loadi").load("secondpage.html");
});
```

```js
$(".add").click(function() {
  var $tr = $('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>').insertAfter('#mytable tr:last');
  //$tr.find(".loadi").load("secondpage.html"); // AJAX...
  $tr.find(".loadi").text("load AJAX content here...");
});
```

```css
.add {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span class="add">Add +</span>
```

Comment: Thank you So much !

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `.load()` inside the `click` handler:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>');
    $(".loadi").load("secondpage.html");
});
```

The issue was you called the `.load()` before click at document ready. If there will be more added rows. Then you might use `.last()` to get the last `.loadi` div:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>');
    $(".loadi").last().load("secondpage.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" colspan="3" style="height:30px;"><div class="loadi"></div></td></tr>');
    // window.open("secondpage.html", '_blank');
     $(".loadi").load("secondpage.html");
  });

})
```

```css
.add {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span class="add">Add +</span>
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using AJAX. `window.location` will transfer the current page entirely. Also note that `href` is a property, not a method, so your code will cause an error.

Comment: @Rory i have update my ans and  you are right..Window.location.herf is not method. its property you can assign url in window.location.herf

Comment: Still, this doesn't do what the OP requires. They specifically state they want to use AJAX, whereas this opens a new window

Comment: Ops sorry..then using this code you can achieve.. $(".loadi").load("secondpage.html");